# Can offspring be less genetically similar to the parent than more distant relatives?

Tags: genetics, sexual-reproduction

I'd be interested in answers about any sexually reproducing species, but for simplicity I'm going to focus on humans in this question.

If the parents are very genetically different (i.e. the number of alleles they share is much less than the average number of alleles shared by 2 people in a population), is it possible for, say, the father to be less genetically similar to his offspring than he is genetically similar to, say, his cousin? If so, what about an even more distant relative?

Of course anything is "possible", so really I'm asking if it's reasonably likely and if so, how likely is it? If, for example, a genetically east Asian person and a genetically south African person had a child, would that child likely be less similar to either parent than the parents are to their respective cousins or even non-relatives from the same area?

If there are any false assumptions I'm making in the question feel free to point them out, but please provide references.

Comment: Provided that a significant percentage of fathers are not biological fathers of their children... ;) More seriously: what is meant by *similarity* here? Genetic similarity or phenotype? I think clarifying this would already suggest the answer.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear I'm talking about genes. Genes determine phenotypes so the questions would have the same answer but the nice thing about genes is theyre quantifiable. You can count the number of alleles.

Comment: Gene are not the only thing determining the phenotype. Moreover, one can easily resemble one parent, despite having 50% of the genes inherited from the other.